# How to block the Gnome Shell Integrations popup from Chrome browser

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

Google Chrome is incapable of using Gnome Shell Integration. But everytime I open Chrome an annoying popup informs me that my "native host connector is not detected." Does anyone know how to yank this out by its roots?

After closing the popup, it pops back up at random intervals. Very annoying.

Oh, yes, I have popup blocker enabled.

[image: Gnome Shell Integration Popup]

Answer (score 1):

There has been an update on the chrome-gnome-shell site which may have resolved the issue:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation

This was what I first tried unsuccessfully because the ne0sight repository was sending a 404 "Page not found" reply. This time it worked so my fingers are crossed that I will not see the annoying popup again.