# Can't uninstall "GNOME Shell integration" extension after uninstalling GNOME

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, gnome-shell

I installed GNOME into my Ubuntu 16.04 installation for a short amount of time. After uninstalling it (with `sudo apt remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`), I still have the "GNOME Shell integration" extension installed into Google Chrome. Unfortunately, I can't remove the extension, because it was installed "administratively":

[image]

How may I get rid of this tumor?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/767765/how-to-block-the-gnome-shell-integrations-popup-from-chrome-browser?rq=1

Comment: This bloatware throws a lot of errors when the desktop environment is KDE.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Figured it out.

From https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation#Troubleshooting:

```
sudo rm /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/chrome-gnome-shell.json
sudo rm /etc/chromium/policies/managed/chrome-gnome-shell.json
```

I also had to these steps:

1. Go to chrome://version/ and copy the profile path
2. Navigate to the profile path and navigate to the Extensions folder
3. Remove the folder named "gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep"
4. Restart Chrome

Comment: Restarting Chrome is not sufficient. It appears that Chrome will cache this information internally for some amount of time. Until this period of time elapses, the extension will remain installed. When Chrome finally does realize, it will however automatically uninstall the extension.

Comment: @badp Edited the answer to also delete the extension folder

Comment: For me step 3 and step 4 is not required after applying `sudo apt remove chrome-gnome-shell`

Comment: Is this not scammy, bloatware behaviour, or is there a valid reason for it auto-installing itself.

Comment: Worked for me without restart.

Comment: @briankip: SInce it's just a package that you can remove like any other, I don't see it as any more bloatware than any other pre-installed package that you may not want to have installed.

Comment: If it just allowed itself to be removed without having to go through extra steps I would agree that it's not spam or bloatware. It might even be useful, but made no attempt to explain why anyone should want to use it.

Comment: ```sudo rm``` the two files works immediately for OpenSuse 42.3. Extra steps not needed.

Comment: Working fine in Ubuntu Studio 17.04

Comment: Adding an extension that you need to do all of this to uninstall is more of the same of what I've come to expect of gnome whose attitude is that they know better than the user and fuck user agency.  Don't beleive me? Look at gnome shell, look at all the preferences and features they've gutted since the initial release. If they keep this up, I think by the time we get gnome-shell 3.48, it's going to look like gnome 2 again.

Answer (score 64):

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-gnome-shell
```

Should get rid of it on Ubuntu without restarting

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You don't even need to restart Chrome for it to work.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: I found it necessary to purge the package as well: "sudo apt-get purge chrome-gnome-shell" and then it went away from Chromium on its own

Comment: Yes it is necessary to use "purge"

Comment: This works on ubuntu 17

Comment: FINALLY. Simply running remove didn't work, only purge. 